# Set command line different color than result text in iTerm2

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm, iterm2

As it is right now, it has become rather annoying having to wade through old result texts through iTerm trying to distinguish where my command line was and what the resulting text is.

Is there a way to make it easier for me to clearly identify my command line?

I was thinking I could set it a different color than my result text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup your shell prompt in a different color please have a look at following two links, one for bash and the other for zsh.

Remember if you ssh to a different host you most likely will lose the color unless you have exactly same settings on that host.

[on-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes)

[crazy bash prompt](http://www.askapache.com/linux/bash-power-prompt.html)